# How to store multiple UITextFields in a Dictionary

Tags: swift

I am looking to initialize a dictionary and then store multiple UITextFields inside of it so that I can do comparisons inside of my UITextField delegate function for formatting the input live. I need to do this because the textFields are created programmatically by Eureka (a form builder) and thus I don't know how else to reference the UITextField created by each particular form cell.

What is the best way of approaching this?

Ideally, I'd want to access the UITextField by doing something like: someDictionaryVar["fieldTag"] which would return the UITextField to me.

Thank you in advance for suggestions/hints! :)

Comment: How do the cells get created? Is there a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or something?

Comment: Using Eureka's custom operators. They have a .cellSetup block where I'd like to assign a key within a dictionary equal to the newly created textField within that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working using:

```
    var formatDict:[String:UITextField] = [:]
```

Assign value in cell's set-up:

```
    formatDict["somekey"] = cell.textField
```

Delegate function:

```
    for (key,value) in formatDict {
        if textField == formateDict[key] {
            print("this is one of the fields!")
        }
    }
```